# Python Telegram bot daily_routine callback not triggered from JobQueue

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have the following bot:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self, handlers: list[BaseHandler], daily_routines):
        self.application = Application.builder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()
        for handler in handlers:
            self.application.add_handler(handler)

        self.job_queue = JobQueue()
        self.job_queue.set_application(self.application)

        for routine in daily_routines:
            self.job_queue.run_daily(routine, time=datetime.time(hour=15, minute=49,
                                                                 tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem')))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.application.run_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _handlers = [
       ...
    ]

    bot = Bot(_handlers, [daily_routine])
    bot()
```

The `daily_routine` is defined as:

```
async def daily_routine(context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    job = context.job
    await context.bot.send_message(job.chat_id, text="HELLO")
```

The `daily_routine` callback isn't triggered on the specified time.

How can I make it work?

Comment: did you test it with shorter time - so you wouldn't have to wait too long for result? Did you try it with different `timezone`? Maybe bot uses different timezone and it may execute it in different moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't [`start`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.start) the `JobQueue`, so it won't process any jobs.

I recommend to instead just use the `JobQueue` instance that the `ApplicationBuilder` provides for you, i.e. `self.application.job_queue`. [`Application.run_polling`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.run_polling) already takes care of starting and stopping that instance.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.